# how to make text go to the far right on a list android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

How can i make, say the location(Westonaria)in the image go to the far right of the "cell" in list view?

[image: Example Cell in my list]

This is my current code, i 1st tried hard coding spaces(Terrible i know) but also tried android:layout_theEndof="@id/currencyTxt" for example?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconImg"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iconImg"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        /><!--done-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userAliasTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iconImg"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/titleTxt"
        /> <!--done-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spacer"
        android:text="             "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/userAliasTxt"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        /><!--done-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currencyTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iconImg"
        android:layout_below="@id/spacer"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#E69611"
        /><!--done-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amountTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/currencyTxt"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#E69611"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@id/spacer"
        /><!--done-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spacer2"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/spacer"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/amountTxt"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    /><!--done-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/locationTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/currencyTxt"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iconImg"
        /><!--done-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the parent layout width Match_Parent
make the price textview width Match_Parent
Now in price textview

```
android:alignParentRight="ture"
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
you need to add both the attributes because `alignParentEnd` targets higher API level and `alignParentRight` targets lower API level. Depending on your minimum sdk level you need to decide which attributes you are going to use.

**Original Answer**

Include the following in your textview:

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
```

Read the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_alignParentEnd)   :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

using the standard `ArrayAdapter` then you could use the constructor:

```
ArrayAdapter<String>(Context, R.layout.aligned_right, values);
```

where `R.layout.aligned_right` is a xml layout like this:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="right"/>
```